# Can a Cleric leave spell slots open to prepare later?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic, cleric

In [another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/can-a-wizard-change-a-spell-they-have-prepared/20095#20095), it's explained that Wizards can leave spell slots blank to be prepared later. I want to know if a Cleric can do the same thing: can a Cleric leave spell slots open when they first prepare spells each day, and prepare spells in those slots later in the day?

Answer (score 17):

**Yes**.

From the [Hypertext d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/divineSpells.htm#preparingDivineSpells):

> Divine spellcasters prepare their spells in largely the same manner as wizards do, but with a few differences. […]
>
> #### Spell Selection and Preparation
>
> A divine spellcaster selects and prepares spells ahead of time through prayer and meditation at a particular time of day. The time required to prepare spells is the same as it is for a wizard (1 hour), as is the requirement for a relatively peaceful environment. **A divine spellcaster does not have to prepare all his spells at once. However, the character’s mind is considered fresh only during his or her first daily spell preparation, so a divine spellcaster cannot fill a slot that is empty because he or she has cast a spell or abandoned a previously prepared spell.**

From [d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Preparing-Divine-Spells):

> #### Spell Selection and Preparation
>
> A divine spellcaster selects and prepares spells ahead of time through prayer and meditation at a particular time of day. The time required to prepare spells is the same as it is for a wizard (1 hour), as is the requirement for a relatively peaceful environment. **When preparing spells for the day, a divine spellcaster can leave some of her spell slots open. Later during that day, she can repeat the preparation process as often as she likes. During these extra sessions of preparation, she can fill these unused spell slots.** She cannot, however, abandon a previously prepared spell to replace it with another one or fill a slot that is empty because she has cast a spell in the meantime. Like the first session of the day, this preparation takes at least 15 minutes, and it takes longer if she prepares more than one-quarter of his spells.

(emphasis added to both quotes)

The "particular time of day" clause limits them only as far as the first daily spell preparation, i.e., the one in which they regain spell slots.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes you can...

> **Spell Selection and Preparation**
>
> A divine spellcaster selects and prepares spells ahead of time through prayer and meditation at a particular time of day. The time required to prepare spells is the same as it is for a wizard (1 hour), as is the requirement for a relatively peaceful environment. A divine spellcaster does not have to prepare all his spells at once. However, the character’s mind is considered fresh only during his or her first daily spell preparation, so a divine spellcaster cannot fill a slot that is empty because he or she has cast a spell or abandoned a previously prepared spell.

*However*, don't forget to "recharge your batteries first."

> **Time of Day**
>
> A divine spellcaster chooses and prepares spells ahead of time, just as a wizard does. However, a divine spellcaster does not require a period of rest to prepare spells. Instead, the character chooses a particular part of the day to pray and receive spells. The time is usually associated with some daily event. If some event prevents a character from praying at the proper time, he must do so as soon as possible. If the character does not stop to pray for spells at the first opportunity, he must wait until the next day to prepare spells.

The recharge your batteries reference is your "ritual" in order to refresh your spell slots from the previous day.

Source: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/divineSpells.htm#preparingDivineSpells