# How Does Acquiring LA+1 Affect Experience Points?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-levels

I want to understand what happens if my character, who has 4000 XP, acquires a LA+1 template during the game.

I understand that since they would be level 3, their ECL would become 4, but what happens to their XP? In my view, there are 2 scenarios:

1. You would have an increase in your XP to 6,000 to represent that ECL, and to level up, you would need 4,000 XP to get to the 10,000 XP needed for a level 5 character.
2. He would still have his 4,000 XP, but since his ECL is 4, he would need to gain 5,000 XP (level 5 = 10,000 XP - 4,000 current XP)?

I appreciate your help and clarification.

| Character Level | XP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1,000 |
| 3 | 3,000 |
| 4 | 6,000 |
| 5 | 10,000 |

Comment: You may also be interested in answers to [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/195302/8610)

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. The response from @HeyICanChan is the clearest and most accurate to my question.