# How can a wizard increase his arcane caster level so that a better improved familiar can be acquired?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, familiars, caster-level

The level 5 wizard changeling substitution level grants the supernatural ability **morphic familiar** that, in part, says

> As a full-round action, the familiar can change its form to that of any creature that the wizard could normally have as a familiar (see page 52 of the *Player’s Handbook*). The wizard gains the new benefi t of the familiar while losing the previous benefit. If the changeling wizard does not have a familiar, this ability has no effect until he gains one. (*Races of Eberron* 123–4)

Assuming my DM is okay with it, my changeling wizard is considering this racial substitution level and the feat **Improved Familiar** (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 200) so as to expand greatly the options that he could normally have as a familiar.

(Note that a DM may *not* be okay with this, reading in that excerpt above *the wizard* as *the wizard class* rather than *the changeling wizard* or reading *normally* as *only those options available in the* Player's Handbook *and excluding all others.* In either case, that makes effort on this question wasted, so answers should assume a generous DM.)

Improved familiars that require an arcane caster level of up to 6 are okay—the Large viper snake (as per *Dragon* #341 89), for instance, or the Small earth elemental (*DMG* 200), the spider swarm (as per *Dragon* #329 98), or even the worg (as per *Complete Warrior* 100)—, but at arcane caster level 7 the myriad of mephits become available as improved familiars (as per *Complete Scoundrel* 78), for example, and mephits make available a host of unusual spell-like abilities, like the spell-like ability *simulacrum* of the mirror mephit (*Expedition to the Demonweb Pits* 208–9).

Just waiting until level 7 isn't an option as this is for a high-op [*E6*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97252/8610) campaign. (I know that's counterintuitive, but don't judge.) Further, the DM has made it clear that a PC should be able to use his trick all day—only once or twice per day or being dependent upon consumables is likely insufficient.

With these binds in mind, is there a way for a changeling wizard 5 or 6 by himself and that has only 11,000 gp to his name to increase forevermore his arcane caster level to 7—ideally, on the cheap—so that he can use the supernatural ability morphic familiar to turn his toad into awesome?

Comment: Why *forevermore*? It's not clear to me that the caster level needs to persist after the familiar morphed; it may only be necessary *when* the morphing occurs.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I didn't want to get too deep into the campaign's binds, but the minicampaign'll only last a few sessions, and one thing the DM recommended is that a PC's trick be usable an unlimited number of times per day. (I suspect the entire campaign will take place over one day.)

Comment: I don't have enough to put together a complete answer, unfortunately. Quickly scanning my index it appears that *Terran Brandy* (Book of Vile Darkness, p. 43) for 500 gp per use, grants a +2 *Alchemical* bonus to CL for 1d20+20 minutes at the cost of 2 points of *Constitution* damage (*Lesser Restoration* to the rescue). When I have more time (and if I remember), I'll try to put together more thorough answer.

Comment: @HeyICanChan you should really include that sort of information in the question.  It's pertinent for the answer.  Likewise if there's a hard level cap for the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't.

Unless the DM is being *particularly* generous, Arcane Spellcaster Level (as required by the [Improved Familiar](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#improved-familiar) feat) is actually your Class Level, and is not improved by things that only improve Caster Level (such as an Orange Prism [Ioun Stone](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#ioun-stones)).

Even prestige classes that improve caster level, spells known and spells per day do not increase familiar abilities unless the specify that they do (Arcane Hierophant, etc.) Not even the kobold ritual "[Greater Draconic Rite of Passage](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060420a)" grants an actual Spellcaster level, but merely a Caster Level and spells known and spells per day (specifically excluding "familiar abilities, and so on" from the improvements)

Even the Obtain Familiar feat [Complete Arcane, p.81], says "For the purpose of determining familiar abilities that depend on your arcane caster class level, your levels in all classes that allow you to cast arcane spells stack." So you'd actually have to get a 7th class level.

Honestly, I don't think that you can get better than 6th level Familiars within the framework of E6.