# When optimizing an E6 character (D&D3.5 variant), can you assume bonus feats whenever convenient, or only at level 6?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, optimization, e6

When optimizing an E6 character (D&D3.5 variant), can you assume bonus feats whenever convenient, or only at level 6?

I’m very familiar with the underlying 3.5 system, but not very familiar with the conventions of E6. It seems like character-build questions handwave feat requirements away freely, but it’s not clear to me how that works. Can you select arbitrary many bonus feats at any arbitrary level? Or is there some known way to achieve the same effect?

Generally, I would expect this sort of question to be “read the book.” However, E6 does not have a “book” per se (or does it?), and to the extent that it does, that book appears different from how common practice appears.

Comment: The canonical [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97252/4563) on this subject has an accepted [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/97255/4563) that includes a [link to the “book”](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?206323-E6-The-Game-Inside-D-amp-D) in its very first sentence. It also answers this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

E6 is a ruleset in which characters level normally until 6th level, including the usual feats at 1st, 3rd, and 6th and whatever bonus feats they may have gotten from class levels. At that point, they cease to gain class levels, and instead gain bonus feats at set XP thresholds (often every 2500 XP). So you *could* assume as many feats as you like *after* 6th, but if you need them *prior* to 6th—say, in order to take a prestige class level with one of your six—then you need to figure out how to make that happen without any extra E6 bonus feats.

Also, nothing in E6 has you ignore feat prerequisites.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot assume bonus feats whenever convenient.  You can assume that E6 characters gain feats in exchange for experience, when they are sixth level, as described by the rules.

Your question has quite a lot of false premises.  You've written:

> It seems like character-build questions handwave feat requirements away freely

and this is wrong, they don't.  You've written:

> E6 does not have a “book” per se

and this is wrong, it's [here](https://www.enworld.org/threads/e6-the-game-inside-d-d.206323/).  In a comment you've written:

> I sincerely appreciate your link here and answer below. That they are not entirely consistent with each other

but this appears to be as wrong as well -- I don't see any inconsistency.

---

Instead of posting a question where you make an offhand statement like "It seems like character-build questions handwave feat requirements away freely...", I think you'd be better served by posting a question like "In this character-build question (link), it looks to me like the accepted answer is handwaving feat requirements.  Is that really the case, and if so, why is it allowed to do that?"

(or simply post that as a comment on the answer that you think is handwaving feat requirements)